# Is there a name for the probability distribution arising from the Hockey-stick Identity?

Tags: distributions, terminology, discrete-data

The Hockey-stick Identity:

${n \choose k} = \sum_{r=k}^n {r-1 \choose k-1}$

This naturally gives rise to a discrete probability distribution with parameters n and k, where the probability mass function is given by

$\text{PMF}(r) = \frac{{r-1 \choose k-1}}{{n \choose k}}$

Does this distribution have a name?

Relevant previous discussion: [Expected value of SRSWOR sample maximum](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/303436/expected-value-of-srswor-sample-maximum/304348)